# Winform: Cursor in wrong location on backslash or delete

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I set up a sort of filter on my textBox in WinForms, to exclude particular characters from being entered by the client. However, I seem to be created new problems that I need help with fixing.

a) Clicking BackSlash causes the cursor to move to the front of the string of characters, rather than remain at the correct position

b) Subsequent clicks of BACKSLASH still causes deletion from the correct location but the cursor remains at the beginning of the string

```
Private Sub txtExp_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtExp.KeyPress
        Dim strtext As String = txtExp.Text 
            If (e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back)) Then
                If (strtext.Length > 0) Then
                    txtExp.Text = strtext.Substring(0, strtext.Length - 1)
                    txtExp.Update()
                End If
            ElseIf (Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "."))) Then
                e.Handled = True
            Else
                txtExp.AppendText(e.KeyChar)
            End If
    End Sub
```

What I would like instead is to have the cursor in the correct location at all times. How do I accomplish this please?

Comment: Brr, this code is using *three* controls.  It makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: for b) Try yourTextBox.Select(), that will put the cursor at the end of the textbox

Comment: Why does handling the KeyPress event in txtPam change the output in txtExp?  What if the user hits the BackSpace in the middle of the text?

Comment: The code does change the contents of another textbox. What I need is to get the cursor to function as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have too much code:

```
Private Sub txtExp_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtExp.KeyPress
  With DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    If (Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "."))) Then
      e.Handled = True
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

You still have a problem with users pasting information into the textbox.  Also, you should probably only allow one decimal point.  Your current code allows multiple decimal points.

It seems like this would really be a job for the [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) control instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need all the code of above, just the part which sets e.Handled.

It is your code that probablly makes problems.